# How can I recreate Trott's Riemann Surface plot in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, color, complex, compatibility

In reading Michael Trott's [Visualization of Riemann Surfaces of Algebraic Functions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3014/RiemannViz.nb?file_id=3077), he has:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], Sqrt[r] Sin[φ/2], SurfaceColor[Hue[φ/(4 π)]]},
                 {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 4 π}, PlotPoints -> {20, 60},
                 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

How would you do this coloring now in *Mathematica* 9?

Answer (score 19):

Natively in version 9, you can do the following:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi], Sqrt[r] Sin[phi/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 {phi, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[#5/(4 Pi)] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: colored Riemann surface]

Alternatively, you can always use the exact code using the V5 emulator:

```
<<Version5`Graphics`
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi], Sqrt[r] Sin[phi/2], 
  SurfaceColor[Hue[phi/(4 Pi)]]}, {r, 0, 1}, {phi, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: version 5 plot]

Of course, the graphics aren't quite as nice.  You can go back to the newer style graphics as follows:

```
<<Version6`Graphics`
```

Answer (score 16):

> As of Version 6, [`SurfaceColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SurfaceColor.html?q=SurfaceColor&lang=en) has been superseded by [`Specularity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Specularity.html?q=Specularity&lang=en) and [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html).

One could specify the variables  explicitly like here :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{ r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], Sqrt[r] Sin[φ/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 4 π},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, φ, θ},
                      {Specularity[#], Glow[#]}& @ Hue[Rescale[φ, {0, 1}]]],
   PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

or adding a more thrilling variation of `ColorFunction` (singularity when `r -> 0`) :

```
ParametricPlot3D[{ r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], Sqrt[r] Sin[φ/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 4 π},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, r, φ, θ},
                       {Specularity[#], Glow[#]}& @ Hue[ Rescale[ φ/r, {0, 1}]]],
    PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you're missing an argument. It should be `Function[{x, y, z, r, φ}, ...]`.

Comment: Yes, I improved the arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

...and now, for something that takes a bit of the old, and a bit of the new:

```
ColoredMakePolygons[vl_List] := Module[{msh = Map[Most, vl, {2}], cols, dims},
        cols = Map[First[Cases[Last[#], _?ColorQ, {0, Infinity}]] &, vl, {2}];
        cols = Map[If[Head[#] === GrayLevel, #, ColorConvert[#, RGBColor]] &,
                   cols, {2}];
        dims = Most[Dimensions[msh]];
        GraphicsComplex[Apply[Join, msh], Polygon[Flatten[Apply[
                        Join[Reverse[#1], #2] &, 
                        Partition[Partition[Range[Times @@ dims], Last[dims]],
                                  {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}], 1]],
                        VertexColors -> Apply[Join, cols]]] /;
ArrayDepth[vl] == 3 && Last[Dimensions[vl]] == 4

With[{m = 21, n = 61}, 
     Graphics3D[ColoredMakePolygons[
                N @ Table[{r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], Sqrt[r] Sin[φ/2], Hue[φ/(4 π)]},
                          {r, 0, 1, 1/(m - 1)}, {φ, 0, 4 π, 4 π/(n - 1)}]], 
                Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

[image: phase-colored Riemann surface, old-style]

Answer (score 1):

[Reference link:](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RiemannSurfaceTransition/)

```
   Manipulate[
     ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate@{Re[(1 - α) (r Exp[
               I φ])^2 + α (r Exp[I φ])^3], 
        Im[(1 - α) (r Exp[I φ])^2 + α (r Exp[
               I φ])^3], r Cos[φ]}, {r, 0, 
       2}, {φ, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> 20, 
      ColorFunction -> (Hue[#5] &), PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, 
      ImageSize -> {435, 435}, Boxed -> False], {{α, 0, "%"}, 0, 
      1}]
```

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface