# How to visualize Riemann surfaces?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, visualization

In `WolframAlpha` we can easily visualize Riemann surfaces of arbitrary functions,

[image]

can we plot the Riemann surface of an arbitrary function using *Mathematica* and with a better color scheme like [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) plots so that I can see the connection of the branches?

[image]

*Edit*

Here are more Riemann surfaces by Matthias Nieser et. [Automatic Generation of Riemann Surface Meshes](http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/ag-geom/publications/db/2010-AutomaticGenerationOfRiemannSurfaceMeshes.pdf)

[image]
[image]
[image]

related:

[How can I recreate Trott's Riemann Surface plot in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/how-can-i-recreate-trotts-riemann-surface-plot-in-mathematica/17058#17058)

[Visualization of Riemann Surfaces of Algebraic Functions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/3014/RiemannViz.nb?file_id=3077)

[Automatic Generation of Riemann Surface Meshes](http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/ag-geom/publications/db/2010-AutomaticGenerationOfRiemannSurfaceMeshes.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps should mention [How can I recreate Trott's Riemann Surface plot in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17055/how-can-i-recreate-trotts-riemann-surface-plot-in-mathematica/17058#17058)

Comment: @Artes That's where confuses me. Does this kind of visualization of the Riemann surface in 3D is called "Trott's Riemann surface plot", or this color scheme is brought up by Trott? There are lots this kind of plot in the wiki page of Riemann surface, but none of them referred to "Trott". Also matlab has a function `cplxmap` that can plot this kind of 3d Riemann surface, and it doesn't mention "Trott" either.

Comment: Take a look at the first sentence in the question from the link Artes provided.

Comment: These are one of a number of ways to depict a Riemann surface. Another way, in my Application, is to use a multifunction capability and show a Riemann plane and using a Locator point with an attached arrow representing the complex value at that point. Dragging around the locator allows one to explore all parts of the surface in a smooth, single valued, continuous manner (just as Riemann claimed). With the Sqrt function you have to circle the origin twice to get back to the same point. You would have to contact me by email for more information.

Comment: This is a link to Riemann surfaces of algebraic functions: jujusdiaries.com

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RiemannSurfacePlot3D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can take Michael Trott's code and modify it a bit to easily plot these surfaces

```
Import["http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/V6/downloads/\
RiemannSurfacePlot3D.m"]
rsurf[func_] := 
  Grid[{{RiemannSurfacePlot3D[w == func, Re[w], {z, w}, 
      ImageSize -> 400, 
      Coloring -> Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[1.4 Im[w]], {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]], 
      PlotPoints -> {40, 40}, Boxed -> False], 
     RiemannSurfacePlot3D[w == func, Im[w], {z, w}, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Coloring -> Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[1.4 Re[w]], {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]], 
      PlotPoints -> {40, 40}, Boxed -> False]}}];
```

Here it is applied to the functions from the OP

```
rsurf /@ {Sqrt[z], Log[z], (z + 1)^(1/3) + (z - 1)^(1/2)}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is a bit tricky to get a nice coordinate mesh in these plots since we aren't actually using a plotting program (like `ParametricPlot3D` or `Plot3D`) to make them.  We are instead building up a list of `Polygon` objects and combining them into a `GraphicsComplex`.  However, we can get a decent approximation of a coordinate mesh by changing the line `EdgeForm[]` to `EdgeForm[Black]`

```
Import["http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/V6/downloads/\
RiemannSurfacePlot3D.m"]
rsurf[func_] := 
  Grid[{{RiemannSurfacePlot3D[w == func, Re[w], {z, w}, 
      ImageSize -> 400, 
      Coloring -> Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[1.4 Im[w]], {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]], 
      PlotPoints -> {30, 20}, Boxed -> False], 
     RiemannSurfacePlot3D[w == func, Im[w], {z, w}, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Coloring -> Hue[Rescale[ArcTan[1.4 Re[w]], {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]], 
      PlotPoints -> {30, 20}, Boxed -> False]}}]/.(EdgeForm[]:>EdgeForm[Black]);
```

You can change the `PlotPoints` above to change the number of polygons drawn, and thus the quality of the 3D image and the density of mesh lines.
The two numbers refer to the azimuthal and radial directions, respectively.

```
rsurf@Sqrt[1 - z^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's nice, could you add the mesh lines for better visualization?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, see the edit.  It took a while to find how to do it since Trott didn't use any built-in plotting functions.  If I were a better mathematician I could deconstruct his package and refit it to use `ParametricPlot3D`, but I couldn't.

Comment: thank you, that looks really nice! ParametricPlot3D was introduced very early (version 2), do you know why he didn't use it in the package?

Comment: I want to say it's because Trott is such a MMA kung-fu master that he doesn't need anything but some polygons and vertex colors to make a better 3D plotting program than is available out of the box.  But there's probably a better reason than that.

Comment: BTW: have you seen Trott's earlier series of articles? You should see there his rationale for his strategy of using `NDSolve[]` in generating these surfaces. (I'm still annoyed that he never got to the special functions.)

Comment: I was hoping that I would be able to use the results from the `NDSolve` as functions to feed to a plotting program.  I've seen some of the writing but didn't read it in detail, my math is not as good as I would like it to be

Comment: @J.M. I'm astonished by how much he knows, not only Mathematica, but also math and physics. Just recently, I was struggled to understand the concepts of Wannier and Bloch states in solid state physics, and found surprisingly that there is a section just describing that in his Guidebook (in relation with Mathieu functions).