# Riemann surface for cubic root

Tags: plotting, complex

I'm trying to generate Riemann surfaces of higher order. I read [How to visualize Riemann surfaces?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31904/how-to-visualize-riemann-surfaces), and the subsequent documents. I'm able to reproduce the surface using polar representation, but I'm having a difficult time generating them using rectangular coordinates, for roots greater then 2. So far what I have is:

```
p1 =
  Plot3D[{Im[(x + I*y)^(1/2)], -Im[(x + I*y)^(1/2)]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> {40, 120}, Mesh -> 25, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]]

p2 =
  ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[({r Cos[#1], 0, (r)^(1/3) Sin[#1/3]} &) /@ {0, π,2 π, 3 π}],
    {r, 0, 2},
    PlotStyle -> {{Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]}}]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Rectangular coordinates and branches in black

```
p3 =
  ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], r^(1/2) Sin[φ/2]}, {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 4 π},
    ColorFunction ->
      Function[{x, y, z, r, φ, θ}, {Specularity[#], Glow[#]}& @ Hue[Rescale[φ, {0, 1}]]],
    PlotPoints -> {20, 60}, Mesh -> 25]

Show[p3, p2]
```

[image]

Polar coordinates with branches in black

The square roots are both identical. If I go on the cubic roots, the polar representation is the same with a change from 2 to 3, but I don't know how to modify the rectangular code to generate the same surface. So for example:

```
p4 =
  ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[φ], r Sin[φ], (r)^(1/3)Sin[φ/3]}, {r, 0, 1}, {φ, 0, 6 π},
    ColorFunction ->
      Function[{x, y, z, r, φ, θ}, {Specularity[#], Glow[#]}& @ Hue[Rescale[φ, {0, 1}]]],
    PlotPoints -> {40, 120},
    Mesh -> 25]

p5 =
  ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[({r Cos[#1], 0, (r)^(1/3) Sin[#1/3]} &) /@ {0, π,2 π, 3 π, 4π, 5π}],
    {r, 0, 2},
    PlotStyle -> {{Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]}}]

Show[p4, p5]
```

[image]

Cubic root in polar with branches in black

I have no idea how to get the same cubic root surface using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume when you wrote "I have no idea how to get the same cubic root surface using polar coordinates", you meant *rectangular* coordinates because you already have the surface in polar coordinates.

In the first plot, `p1`, you're plotting `Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)]` and `Im[-(x + I y)^(1/2)]` because $1$ and $-1$ are the two square roots of unity. To plot cube roots, you just have to use the cube roots of unity, namely $1$, $e^{2\pi i/3}$, and $e^{4\pi i/3}$:

```
Plot3D[
  {Im[(x + I y)^(1/3)], 
   Im[E^(2 I Pi/3) (x + I y)^(1/3)], 
   Im[E^(4 I Pi/3) (x + I y)^(1/3)]},
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> {40, 120}, Mesh -> 25, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]
 ]
```

[image: Riemann surface of cube root]

(I didn't change any of the other options in your plot.)