# Drawing a hyperelliptic Riemann surface

Tags: plotting, complex, visualization

I'm trying to draw the Riemann surface defined by the polynomial $z^2=w^5-w$, where $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers.  I'm a new user of *Mathematica*, and I tried manipulating some examples I found, but with no luck.  Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114853/731) answer?

Comment: Yes I have seen it, but I don't know how to get to work.  I'll try again.

Comment: I'm supposed to get a genus 2 surface but I don't get that!

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2010/02/on-the-visualization-of-riemann-surfaces/

Answer (score 3):

Trott gives a simple technique in [his article](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/articles/3014/) on rendering Riemann surfaces. At the time, he had said:

> Although in principle this method works (…) for higher order polynomials the `Resultant` calculation will become much more expensive. Also, the generation of a high resolution `ContourPlot3D` requires much CPU time…

Nowadays, with more powerful computers, the method is now slightly more feasible to do:

```
expr = Expand[w^5 - w - z^2 /. {z -> x + I y, w -> u + I v}];

ip = Total[Expand[Cases[expr, _Complex _]/I]];
rp = Expand[expr - I ip];

resRe = Resultant[rp, ip, v];
resIm = Resultant[rp, ip, u];

{ContourPlot3D[resRe == 0, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {u, -2, 2}, 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
               BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[2/3, ColorData[97, 3]],
               MaxRecursion -> 1, Mesh -> False, PlotLabel -> "real part",
               PlotPoints -> 55, PlotRange -> All],
 ContourPlot3D[resIm == 0, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, {v, -2, 2}, 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "v"}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
               BoxRatios -> {3, 3, 2}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[2/3, ColorData[97, 1]],
               MaxRecursion -> 1, Mesh -> False, PlotLabel -> "imaginary part",
               PlotPoints -> 55, PlotRange -> All]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Riemann surface for z^2 = w^5 - w]

The artifacts along the surfaces' self-intersections is due to my inability to increase `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` on my computer; a better computer than mine may be able to make a better picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
ResourceFunction["RiemannSurfacePlot3D"][z^2 == w^5 - w, Re[z], {w, z}]
```

[image]