# How to reproduce the Riemann Surface of `Log[z]`

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) plot on Wikipedia:

[image]

which is the plot of the

> *multi-valued imaginary part of the complex logarithm function, which shows the branches.*

So I tried to reproduce myself with the code:

```
myGradient = (Blend[{{0.345556, RGBColor[0.985, 0., 0.870436]}, {0, 
       RGBColor[0.359518, 0., 0.81767]}, {1, 
       RGBColor[0.443748, 1., 0.0305638]}, {0.572157, 
       RGBColor[0.985946, 0., 0.0269474]}, {0.79284, 
       RGBColor[1., 1., 0.041413]}}, #3] &);


Plot3D[{Im[Log[x + I y]], Im[Log[x + I y]] + 2 Pi, 
  Im[Log[x + I y]] + 4 Pi}, 
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Mesh -> 25, 
  ColorFunction -> myGradient
 ]
```

which produces the output:

[image]

As you can notice I wasn't able to reproduce the curvy grid, which, instead, is the normal square grid of the `Plot3D` function. Further mor I have those strange white spaces which I would like to cover, to obtain an image the more similar to the one on Wikipedia.

Some ideas?

## EDIT:

I already read [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31904/how-to-visualize-riemann-surfaces) but by plotting with that code the `Log[z]` function I obtain this result:

[image]

which is clear not what I want.

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31904/how-to-visualize-riemann-surfaces

Comment: No, I saw that, but basically it gives another figure for the `Log[z]` function, and not the grid I want, I'll make an edit to be more clear

Comment: The grid must get bigger when displacing from the (0, 0, z) line...

Comment: so the surface is correct, you just want different mesh lines?  The first question to ask is, what function of `z` do the mesh lines you want follow?  The wikipedia page isn't clear on that.

Comment: What if you added `MeshFunctions -> {#1^2 + #2^2 &, ArcTan[#2, #1] &}` as an option in the `Plot3D` call? That might not be quite it, but if you can figure out what the contour lines are, then you can adapt these functions to that.

Comment: No, actually I would like that I could plot the function as I did (as planes instead of a surface)... for the mesh lines I don't understand how they did, and, yes, he wikipedia page is not clear, but I need them to look like their ones. 
If I would know the function of `z` it is following I'll be probably able to solve the problem... I'm sorry I can't help more

Comment: @march they're not still what I want, because in the plot I posted the mesh lines correspond to the transformation of the perpendicular line on the complex plane that the `Log[z]` function operates on the plane...

Comment: So, why did you not then try `MeshFunctions` with the real and imaginary parts of the logarithm?

Comment: @J.M. I was just elaborating my own answer with that solution, I got actually the plot that I wanted (with the conformal mapping of the Log function), I did not realised at first that it should be obviously the level set of the two real functions composing the complex one. I'll post as soon as possible, if anyone answer.

Comment: If, as you say, you've figured it out, please do answer your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was looking for was to obtain the mesh lines of the mapping of a square grid on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ under the `Log[z]` transformation. So actually, to obtain the mesh lines in the image I posted (which is actually not so precise, as the lines coming from the origin don't seem to be straight lines), using the command `MeshFunction`, as suggested by [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march), who I thank, you only need to provide to it as functions respectively the imaginary and real part of the `Log[z]`:

```
Plot3D[{Im[Log[x + I y]], Im[Log[x + I y]] + 2 Pi, 
  Im[Log[x + I y]] - 2 Pi},
    {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.5},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 50, 
    Mesh -> 30,
    MeshFunctions -> {Im[Log[#1 + I #2]] &, Re[Log[#1 + I #2]] &},
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    ColorFunction -> mycolor
 ]
```

color palette to obtain some very similar result is reported below

```
mycolor = (
   Blend[
     {
      {1, RGBColor[0.512917, 1., 0.0319219]},
      {0.669069, RGBColor[1., 1., 0.041413]}, {0.461286, 
       RGBColor[0.985946, 0., 0.0269474]},
      {0.226004, RGBColor[0.985153, 0., 0.79292]},
      {0, RGBColor[0.495415, 0., 0.998459]}
      },
     (1 - #3)]
    &);
```

[image]

Comment: The palette "mycolor" is not defined in the above code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add, I found the notebook.