# Plotting a projection of a branch cut on the real plane

Tags: plotting, complex

How can I obtain a plot describing the shape of a branch cut on the real plane?[image]

Comment: ...but that function has a pole, and not a branch cut.

Comment: This is how branch cut is defined, it has not only a single pole, but rather a continuum of poles.

Comment: What "continuum of poles"?  Please be specific.  Regardless, try:  `ComplexPlot[1/(z - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}]`

Comment: A function has to be multivalued to start with to have brach cut. How is f(z)=1/(z-a) multivalued? Maybe you mean something else other than branch cut?

Comment: a is considered an undetermined parameter, and one obtains set of outputs for each input of z. Anyway, all I am asking is for the plot that will be obtained by "cutting the attached figure in the middle", by inserting an "xy" or "xz" plane.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion I believe the user is requesting how to obtain the Riemann surface representation of a multivalued function in Mathematica. Specifically the Riemann surface for the log function as in this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface. If that is the case, they seem to be asking how to "unravel" the branch cut.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As I recall a sequence of converging rational approximations of a function with a branch cut has an evergrowing number of poles that coalesce around the branch cut. I do not remember if this is always true but if it is, one can view a branch cut as a continuum of poles.  The simplest example might be a Riemann sum approximation of an integral like F[z]=Integral[1/(z-x),{x,0,1}] which will have poles at k/n where n is the number of terms in the sum and k is the bound index.

Comment: The user seems to be a physicist familiar with quantum field theory. Poles in quantum field theory have a physical interpretation as particles. If my memory is correct (it is vague at the moment), branch cuts in quantum amplitudes of particle collisions represent the possibility of creating multi-particle states with a continuum of possible energies for the particles. OP might thus have this interpretation of continuum of poles when referring to functions with branch cuts

Comment: @Yair I do not know if you deleted a previous comment as I did not understand the discussion with Nasser, Maybe you wanted to mention `F[z]=Integral[1/(z-x),{x,0,1}]` as an example of a function with a branch cut on [0,1]

Comment: If you would like to obtain the plot in that image then you can maybe use https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153442. If instead you really want the projection of that staircase onto the complex plot then you can you can use `ComplexPlot`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! @userrandrand I never erased any comment, I edited my post since I am less interested in the mathematical aspect, but just interested in getting a plot :)

Comment: What you want is the intersection between a plane of constant x and the Riemann surface ?

Comment: Yes, indeed userandand. Do you know how to generate a plot of that?

Comment: You should use @ like @Yair so that a user may be notified. Maybe you want something like `x = 4; Plot[Table[Im[Log[x + I*y]] + 2*Pi*k, {k, -1, 1}], {y, -8, 8}]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Its the plot of the Riemann surface of  z -> Log[z]  in a polar coordinates mesh with decks in an regular hight as multiples of 2 pi.

ComplexPlot3D is able to draw the central deck around z=1, Log z =0.

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[z]*Exp[ Arg[z]/\[Pi]] , {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I},
  Mesh -> {12, 12},  
MeshStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Yellow}, {Thickness[0.005], Orange}},
AxesLabel -> {"Re z", "Im z",    " e^arg z "} ,
 Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {"Re z", "Im z", "e ^ (arg z)"} ,  
PlotLabel -> Style[" z \[Function]  log z * Exp arg z ", 16]  , 
PlotRange -> {-1, 20}]
```

[image]

A plot of the Riemann surface as an infinte car park deck can be done by

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Log[r] Cos[\[Phi]], 
  Log[r] Sin[\[Phi]], \[Phi]/(\[Pi])}, {\[Phi], -2.5 \[Pi], 
  2.5 \[Pi]}, {r, 1/10, 10}, 
 Mesh -> {30, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[ 16 #4/\[Pi], 16 #4/\[Pi], 0.8] &),
 AxesLabel -> {"Re z", "Im z", "Arg z"}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Evaluate[({#, #*"\[Pi]"} &) /@ Range[-3, 3]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[" z \[Function] {Re log z, Im log z, arg z}", 16]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roland. Although interesting, this is not exactly what I asked for. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see you want that straight lines?

By inspection the surface looks like a minimal surface attached to a staircase of straight lines .

You may verify the conjecture by converting the image to a vector graphics, Select   all points with one coordinate on one border and Interpolate.

Answer (score 1):

First some clairification:  Your plot looks like the imaginary component of $\log(z)$.  If you wish to draw horizontal and vertical lines on this surface, can do so like this for example a horizontal blue line at $z=x+0.5i$ and a vertical red line at $z=0.5+yi$ on the principal branch:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{0.5, Im@z, Arg@z} /. z -> 0.5 + I y, {y, -1, 
    1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0.5, Arg@z} /. z -> x + 0.5 I, {x, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue];
p3 = Plot3D[Arg@z /. z -> x + I y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue];
p4 = Plot3D[Arg@z /. z -> x + I y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightBlue];

Show[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

If this is what you want you can access the other sheets by adding additional plot commands by modifying p3 and p4 using 2 n Pi+Arg[z] with $n$ and integer and remembering to plot around the default branch-cut of log used by Mathematica at the negative real axis.  That's why I split up the plot into p3 and p4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Josh! this is getting closer to what I am asking. I want a 2D plot (and not 3D), but what I failed to do is to include a few branches on the same image. Can you help please?

Comment: @Yair:  Don't understand what 2-D plot you want.  Maybe you can give an example.