# Riemann surface of the argument multivalued function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, graphics3d, complex

I tried to use Michael Trott's Mathematica Resource function RiemannSurfacePlot3D for plotting the Riemann surface of the Arg function without success. How can I plot this Riemann function with the Wolfram language?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: As far as I can see the graph of arg z is plotted there, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114853/9469. Please have a look at the imaginary part of the logarithm function. Please notice $\mathrm{Log} z= \log|z|+i\mathrm{Arg} z$

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ComplexPlot3D[Arg[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, understood.  We cannot display infinitely many sheets, $\cdots,$  but we can display a few of them.  Here are 21:

```
Plot3D[Table[ArcTan[x, y] + 2 \[Pi] k, {k, -10, 10}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[21 z]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is a plot of Abs[Arg[z]] not a Riemann surface which has infinite sheets

Comment: Ok, thanks for so many sheets! :)