# Remove the blank of branch cuts

Tags: plotting, complex

```
H = {{I*(x + I*y), 1}, {1, -I*(x + I*y)}};
{x1, x2} = Eigenvalues[H];

Plot3D[{Im[x1], Im[x2]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightRed}, Mesh -> 0]
```

[image]

There is a white blank on the surface because of the branch cut. How to remove this "white line" to make the two surfaces as a whole part?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100973/plotting-riemann-surface-of-wz-sqrt1-z2

Answer (score 5):

The desired imaginary parts are represented by `v` in algebraic formulation below.  Put `u` before `v` in the variables for `GroebnerBasis` to get the first polynomial to define `v` in terms of `x` and `y`.  Reverse (`v` before `u`, both before `x, y`) to get the real part `u` in terms of `x` and `y`.

```
branches = u + I v - Eigenvalues[H];
surf = Times @@ branches // Simplify;
parts = ReIm[surf] // ComplexExpand;
gb = GroebnerBasis[parts, {u, v, x, y}];
ContourPlot3D[
 First[gb] == 0 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {v, -2, 2},
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> LightRed, MaxRecursion -> 6, 
 PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Added alternative:***

Another way that happens to remove the branch-cut jump (the use of polar coordinates is similar to Henrik's, but it's the combination with `ComplexExpand` that moves the branch cut to the boundary of the plot):

```
imEVs = FullSimplify[
   ComplexExpand[Im@Eigenvalues[H], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}],
   x > 0 && -1 < y < 1];
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Thread[{x, y, imEVs}],
 {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> LightRed, Mesh -> None, 
 Exclusions -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Using polar coordinates helps a little

```
plot = With[{
   opts = 
    Sequence[PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightRed}, Mesh -> 0, 
     PlotPoints -> {73, 20},
     BoundaryStyle -> None,
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}
     ],
   ϵ = 1. 10^-6,
   aa = {x, y, Im[x1]} /. {x -> 1 + r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]},
   bb = {x, y, Im[x2]} /. {x -> 1 + r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]}
   },
  Show[
   ParametricPlot3D[aa, {t, ϵ, 2 Pi - ϵ}, {r, 0, 2},
     opts],
   ParametricPlot3D[bb, {t, ϵ, 2 Pi - ϵ}, {r, 0, 2},
     opts]
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

However, the slit can still be seen from different view points. But one can try and glue the two `GraphicsComplex`es within `plot` together in order to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat inelegant, but works?

```
Plot3D[{Max[Im[x1], Im[x2]], Min[Im[x1], Im[x2]]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightRed}, Mesh -> 0, ExclusionsStyle -> LightRed]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun note the eigenvalue expression is:
    $\lambda^2=1-(x^2+2ixy-y^2)=1-(x+iy)^2$.
Letting $z=x+iy$ we have the expression
    $\lambda=\sqrt{1-z^2}$

So basically, $\lambda$ is just the square root function offset to x=1. And one easy way to plot this is:

```
myf[z_] := Sqrt[1 - z^2];
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{Re[z], Im[z], Im@myf[z]} /. 
   z -> 1 + r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Re[z], Im[z], -Im@myf[z]} /. 
   z -> 1 + r Exp[I t], {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
Show[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]